# How to show the validation error message on a form in php?

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to make a validation script in php for a register form. The problem that I have is that the error message doesn't show and I can't figure out the problem. I've tried different sources but something is escaping my eye

This is in the **register-page.php** file. The problem code is the php one in the  tag

```
<form method="post" action="register-user.php" class="col-12" id="login-position">
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['errors'])){
 echo $_SESSION['errors'];                     
 }
?>
</form>
```

And this is in the register-user.php:

```
array_push($error, "User already exists");} ($error is the array where I put the error messages.


if (count($error) == 0)
        {

            //some code to insert into database, works fine
        }

    else {
          $_SESSION['errors'] = $error;
          header("Location: register-page.php");
          exit;
    }
```

Nothing is printed on the screen. As a mention at the head of the file I have $session_start(). When I click on the submit button, I expect the page to refresh and show the error message. Can you please help?

Comment: `$session_start()` or `session_start()`? Also, will the session variable not be an array? You can't `echo` an array

Comment: start session `session_start()` and then try using "print_r()" `print_r($_SESSION['errors']);`

Comment: If `$_SESSION['errors']` is an array, you should not simply `echo` it

Comment: session_start() sorry for the typo

Comment: Link here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5be1f97afacf7db05249407e11987f0a37850378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your question:

```
echo $_SESSION['errors'];
```

will never work since you are trying to echo an array (as you stated before).

Try doing

```
print_r $_SESSION['errors'];
```

to see if the content is there. Then you can loop the array to print each item inside.

First you need to put a

```
session_start();
```

on top of the file where you want to access the $_SESSION values

Comment: The print_r function worked. The session_start was already there but I really appreciate your answer.